# Зависает сайт на несколько секунд при загрузке (yandex map)

Tags: html, jquery, css

простой лендинг на wp. Использовал только bootstrap4 и owl-carousel
[ссылка на сайт](http://roomicom.ru)

Отключал модули по одному, всеравно зависает, в чем может быть проблема? из за двух каруселей?

**upd**

Как я понял проблема в двух версиях карты яндекс.
т.к. никак не получалось сделать в одной версии сразу две карты на сайт, решил две карты сделать двумя разными версиями 2.1 и 2.0 и походу из за этого тормозит, как решить проблему?
**upd**

Проблема не в ямапе

Comment: Попробуйте загружать `js` в конце страницы, а не в начале

Comment: @NikitaSmith пробовал, никак

Comment: не смотрел в консоле разработчика как загружаются ресурсы(время загрузи и  порядок)

Comment: Две и более карт разместить можно с одним скриптов Я.карт. Откройте другой вопрос, если хотите узнать, как это сделать.

Comment: @TotalPusher как оказалось проблема не в ямапе

Comment: Если считаете нужным, напишите решение вашей проблемы как ответ на свой вопрос.